# Use image url in text box to display pic after submit

Tags: html

Using html for my page I have a text box and a submit button. I want to be able to put an image url into the text box, click submit, and have the image display below the submit button. I DO NOT want to upload a picture as a file. I have looked around for how to do this but have not had any luck. Any ideas?

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="imglink" value="insert image URL here" onclick="this.select()"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Load Image">
</form>
```

Comment: We'll need more information. Where's your code? What file upload system are you using? Where are you storing the image? etc...

Comment: I'm not uploading a file. Please read my details carefully. I want to put an image URL into a text box, click submit, and have the image be displayed below the submit button using only the url as a source. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example, with pure Javascript. Instead of "submit" i used "button" to not submit the form.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="url" name="imglink" id="imglink"  placeholder="Insert image URL here" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Show Image" id="btn1" />
</form>
<div id="photo"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('photo').innerHTML = '<img src="'+ document.getElementById('imglink').value +'" alt="Image" />';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will allow you to enter a url and upload under your submit button. Ensure that you have jquery available for this to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/7L031bfj/

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="photo"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var photo = $('#input').val();
  $('#photo').append('<img src=' + photo + '>')
});
```

Comment: That would be ok if I wanted to upload the picture. But I want to use the picture's url instead.

Comment: updated answer to add url and have it appear under photo. Also, please note you need to include jquery for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using text box, you can use this Attribute `<input type="file">`.

Comment: That would be ok if I wanted to upload the picture. But I want to use the picture's url instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, as i am also slightly unclear as what you want

https://jsfiddle.net/q65rxcbg/

```
<input type="text" id='imglink' value="insert image URL here">
<br>
<input type="submit" id='submit' value="Load Image">
<br/>
<img id='photo'>

$('#submit').click(function () {
    var selectedFile = $('#imglink').val();
    $('#photo').attr("src", selectedFile);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this did not work, even on the jsfiddle testing page. The image does not display. It appears broken. I need it to take the image url and use it to display the actual, original image on the page.